# Debugging an ASP.NET website with user controls, creates a dll for each control, causing slowness in loading

Tags: asp.net, performance, user-controls

Ok, so I have an asp.net web project, with arround 15 user controls (inside the same project).

Question 1: 
When I debug the application, I find that asp.net compiles a seperate dll for each user control is this normal, can this be changed?

Question 2:
When Opening any page the first time that uses a couple of these controls, it takes around 20 seconds for visual studio to load all these dlls, as I can see in the output window;
a sample line of a loaded dll:
    'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/Project/Project-1-130975012827135020): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Project\e52af586\3ad8a5ff\App_Web_ctlstep_objection.ascx.431b080c.43i_q30y.dll'.

Does anyone know the cause of the slowness?
Is it because the user controls are compiled to seperate dlls as mentioned above?

Environment:
ASP.NET Web Project
.NET Framework 4
Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
Window 8.1 64bit

Comment: I don't think this is normal. Sounds like a website publish setting you may need to tweak. If you go into the publish settings for your web project, then go into the Advanced Precompile Settings and see which "Merge" settings you have selected. Try the "Do not merge" option if you have something else selected. More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx  Also try unchecking the "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" option and retest.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Unfortunately I'm not publishing, this happens when hitting f5, and I also checked these settings incase they have an effect, but the "_Precompile during publishing_" option was already unchecked.